# Ruby hash.delete(:key) deleting copies and clones as well

Tags: ruby, hash, clone, dup

From what I understand, when you set an object = to another, it will always be a reference, so we have methods like `.dup` and `.clone` to actually create a copy of an object and not a reference.

However, I am duplicating or cloning an array of hashes and then when I delete a key from the original hash they are being deleted from the copies! This is not supposed to happen, I wonder what I'm doing wrong.

Code:

```
or_data = {title: 'some title', tracks: [ { name: 'track one', position: 0, 
  artist: 'orignal artist', composer: 'original composer', duration: '1:30' }, 
  { name: 'track two', position: 1, artist: 'some other guy', 
  composer: 'beethoven', duration: '2:10' } ]  }

new_hash = or_data.dup
# or new_hash = or_data.clone, either way produces the same result

or_data[:tracks].each { |e| e.delete(:position) }
```

The `:position` key will also be deleted from `new_hash`!

This happens regardless of whether I use `.dup` or `.clone`.

I just read a post that says one should use:

```
new_hash = Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(or_data) )
```

This does work. But why? Because `.dup` and `.clone` do "shallow copies" meaning they will create a reference to `:tracks` (in this example) instead of a copy because it is an array of hashes contained within a hash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the code below:

```
or_data = {title: 'some title', tracks: [ { name: 'track one', position: 0, artist: 'orignal artist', composer: 'original composer', duration: '1:30' }, { name: 'track two', position: 1, artist: 'some other guy', composer: 'beethoven', duration: '2:10' } ]  }
new_hash = or_data.dup

p "Using .dup"
p "-----------"
p "or_data : #{or_data.object_id}"
p "new_hash : #{new_hash.object_id}"

p "or_data[:tracks] :#{or_data[:tracks].object_id}"
p "new_hash[:tracks] : #{new_hash[:tracks].object_id}"


or_data[:tracks].each { |e| e.delete(:position) }


new_hash = Marshal.load( Marshal.dump(or_data) )

p "Marshalling"
p "-----------"
p "or_data : #{or_data.object_id}"
p "new_hash : #{new_hash.object_id}"

p "or_data[:tracks] :#{or_data[:tracks].object_id}"
p "new_hash[:tracks] : #{new_hash[:tracks].object_id}"
```

Output:

```
"Using .dup"
"-----------"
"or_data : 5282580"
"new_hash : 5282568"
"or_data[:tracks] :5282592"
"new_hash[:tracks] : 5282592"

"Marshalling"
"-----------"
"or_data : 5282580"
"new_hash : 5282172"
"or_data[:tracks] :5282592"
"new_hash[:tracks] : 5282112"
```

The reason the `position` key gets deleted when using `.dup` or `.clone` is because the `tracks` key still refers to the same array object. Where as after Marshalling the `tracks` key refers to an entire new array object.

Answer (score 1):

You are cloning `Hash object` not `Hash values`. It doesn't perform nested cloning.

In your case array (`[ { name: 'track one', position: 0, artist: 'orignal artist', composer: 'original composer', duration: '1:30' }, { name: 'track two', position: 1, artist: 'some other guy', composer: 'beethoven', duration: '2:10' } ]`) is referencing the same object on `clone` or `dup`